# Data Scientist Consulting Interview Guide

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone have any books or blogs that specifically sheds light on questions to ask your organization (from a consulting POV) as a data scientist? I am a new data scientist, which I have a background in consulting and predictive analytics.

There are several good reads such as "The Data Scientist's Field Guide" by Booz Allen, "The McKinsey Mind" from McKinsey, or maybe "Business Analytics for Managers" from SAS. I have come across interview guides to understand and execute strategy, but none that specifically structure questions for a preliminary assessment of analytic capability.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://datadrivenculture.org/CCI_Analytics_Capability_Assessment%202017.pdf) might be a resource that you would be interested in. It's a preliminary assessment for health centers, but a lot of the structure can be used in any industry.

Comment: Interesting template to use. Thank you for the share. It would be interesting to see specific questions used to address analytic capability on a granular level for each one of these assessment areas for the healthcare industry. Thanks again.